# Handling multiple UICollectionView' interactiveMovements - Crash: UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator is already being interacted with

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

***(See Update 3 for more information. I fixed the original problem, now there's an exception I've never seen before)***

so I've been trying to implement my own version of IOS11' Drag&Drop feature. I've implemented a custom `gesture recognizer` and my own drag and drop session manager, called `DragAndDropSession`.

The situation with my app is the following: I have a "fullscreen" vertically scrolling `collectionView`, that holds horizontally scrolling `collectionView`s in each cell (row). A bit like what netflix has, for instance.

While dragging an item, I want these horizontal `collectionView`s to dynamically make space for the dragged item (just like with IOS11' Drag&Drop). I do that by adding an invisible cell to the row's `collectionView` and then I use `collectionView.beginInteractiveMovement(..)` on that cell. This way, it looks like a gap is moving around when I constantly update it to the current touch position. (I haven't found a better way).

Each time the touch moves to a different row, I stop the first `interactive movement`, remove the empty cell, and add it to the new `collectionView`, where I again begin an `interactive movement`. The difficulty here is the managing aspect so that everything gets "cleaned up" and then set up again correctly.

As this is hard to explain, **I created a demo project** showcasing everything (including the crash I'm going to tell you about in a second):

https://github.com/d3mueller/DragAndDropTest
*(I hope it's working. Let me know, if not)*

A few things:

- It's a work in progress. dropping an item isn't implemented, so don't try that :D. Things will happen, that should not happen. I only implemented dragging
- I'm using `IGListKit` (https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit) to manage my `collectionViews`. It's probably not relevant to my problem, though. (I tried to comment the important bits)
- In my code, you'll often see `...SectionController`. This is the "manager" of a cell in the collectionView (IGListKit). For instance, the rows in the vertically scrolling `collectionView` each have a section controller that contains the data for this row, and the collectionView for this row etc.
- In the following, I'll try to explain my problem. Sadly, I can't really post actual code snippets here, because you need to know the context to understand what happens there. That's why I added the demo project.

---

Okay, now to my problem: It's crashing. Sometimes. It gives me this error message:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to begin reordering on collection view while reordering is already in progress'

I set a breakpoint to catch this exception, so I know that it crashes in `DragAndDropSession.swift: Line 194`, which is this:

```
rowCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: rowIndexPath)
```

In this line, I start a new interactive movement for the collectionView row that the finger is currently hovering on. I just don't know why it gets to this line, when it already has begun an interactive movement. A few lines above (line 171) I cancel the interactive movement.

There is a specific case/situation I'm not covering/catching in my code. I just can't find it. I've spent hours on this.

---

**How to reproduce this bug (Look at Update 2. I found a way)**:

*(I only managed to reproduce it on my iPad, not in the simulator)*

Long press any item, move it a bit and then use another finger (while still holding the dragged item) to quickly scroll up and down and left and right. You have to be really fast and chaotic. Then it sometimes crashes.

**The cause:**
*First, it's likely to be the `updateDrag()` method in `DragAndDropSession.swift`.*

The error says I'm trying to begin reordering while another reordering is already in progress. Thus, in some cases I begin it twice **or** I don't cancel the movement before beginning another. I just don't know why.

---

### UPDATE:

Sometimes, a different error is being trown (at the same line, after doing the exact same thing):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<_UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c0134dc0: prepared=1> is already being interacted with'

I have never seen this before. The only thing I found about this, is this bug report: https://openradar.appspot.com/42139082

Any ideas?

---

### UPDATE 2:

I found a way to reproduce it 100% of the time (I updated the demo project to add more rows and remove the empty row):

[image]

Steps to reproduce (also see gif):

1. long press an item to begin dragging it.
2. While still dragging the item, use the second finger to scroll at least 2 rows down. While you do this, you *musn't* move the first finger. It has to be perfectly still. Also, it has to be *one* swipe gesture to scroll.
3. Before the scrolling stops, scroll up (again using only one swipe gesture) until you reach the row *directly below* the one you started out with. Stop there (using the second finger or wait until it stops by itself)
4. Move the first finger (that's dragging the item) which will create a gap in that row.
5. Now, whenever you move the first finger onto the row you started out with, it crashes.

---

### UPDATE 3:

I've fixed the original problem with the `attempt to begin reordering on collection view while reordering is already in progress`. It took me quite some time, the problem was occurring when a row leaves the screen (that's why you needed to scroll down quite a bit before it crashes). When the row then came back, a possibly different cell would be dequeued, thus I couldn't cancel the interactive movement from the original one. I fixed this by saving the collectionView itself (contained by the row). This and a couple small fixes did the trick. However, now I'm getting the following error (as introduced in Update 1) all the time it crashes.

> 2018-07-27 18:33:06.866322+0200 DragAndDropTest[62655:8122083] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator userInteractionStarted], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.54.4/_UIDragFeedbackGenerator.m:175
>   2018-07-27 18:33:06.867191+0200 DragAndDropTest[62655:8122083] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<_UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c012c9e0: prepared=1> is already being interacted with'

I haven't found a reliable way to reproduce this yet, but it's fairly easy to trigger. Just move the dragging item around a bit and scroll etc.

The big problem now is that I have absolutely no idea what this is. I've never seen this before, I don't know how to debug it. Has anyone ever seen this?

Again, I updated the demo project.

---

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could take a look at this. It's probably something trivial I'm not seeing. Let me know if you need any more information

Thank you!

Comment: I am currently hunting a bug with the exact same crash-log-information. Did you ever figure out what caused it for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This was extremely hard to debug and there is no documentation (as far as I know). I ended up creating my own drag&drop system from the ground up.

Comment: So you mean you ditched the system provided by `UICollectionView`? May I ask how you did it?

Comment: Yep. That's a long story. In Short: First, I created a gesture recognizer that basically detects the same gestures as Drag&Drop does (long hold to trigger, pan to move around and tapping with a second finger to add items to the drag). Then I originally wanted to create a custom layout that's dynamically moving the items to create a "gap" when dragging something over it. However, that created a whole lot of other problems so what I am doing now is: I literally insert an empty cell below the drag location (and move this cell around). That's working pretty well and allows me to customise a lot.

Comment: I should add that I'm using `IGListKit` which makes this "adding and moving cells around" extremely easy and convenient. It's also pretty fast doing it.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same assertion failure using iOS 11 Collection View Drag and Drop API in combination with interactive move (`beginInteractiveMove` etc).

Since this scenario is very specific and edge-casey, your mileage may vary.

I ventured into the rabbit hole and figured out the following:

- `_UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator` is a private subclass of `UIFeedbackGenerator` which is responsible for haptic feedback
- [`UIFeedbackGenerator` Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator#2555460):

  > #### Releasing the Generator
  >
  > If you no longer need a prepared generator, remove all references to the generator object and let the system deallocate it. This lets the Taptic Engine return to its idle state.
- This *could* mean that for some reason the interactive move / reordering session is not completely finished although you may have called `cancelInteractiveMovement()`. The feedback generator remains in a prepared state (→ `reason: '<_UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c012c9e0: prepared=1>` from the assertion failure log) and will not let go of this state until it is deallocated by the system.

What fixed it for me was overriding `cancelInteractiveMovement` in my UICollectionView subclass and calling both `super.cancelInteractiveMovement` and `super.endInteractiveMovement`:

```swift
override func cancelInteractiveMovement() {
    super.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    super.endInteractiveMovement() // ← will not perform the standard "end" animation
    // the moving cell was already reset by cancelInteractiveMovement
}
```

This seems to clean up the unfinished `UIFeedbackGenerator` and does not crash anymore (so far).

#### Related links

- http://www.openradar.me/42139082 (closed rdar)
- http://www.openradar.me/42154922 (duplicate of above, still open)

Answer (score 2):

Although it's been quite a while since this was originally asked, there's still little information on the <_UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c012c9e0: prepared=1> is already being interacted with' error out there and we were experiencing it quite regularly in our app even after implementing the override cancelInteractiveMovement() call in the answer from [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574111/14076779).
When I dropped breakpoints on the cancelInteractiveMovement it was very rarely called.
I've implemented the following on the drag delegate for the collection views and so far have not seen any of the UIDragSnappingFeedbackGenerator crashes yet.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionDidEnd session: UIDragSession) {
    
    collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
}
```

Still TBD if there will be downstream consequences for this.